# How do I know whether my disk C: is on the SSD or on the HDD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, windows-explorer

I bought an SSD and I cloned the system from the HDD to the SSD using the Minitool Partition Wizard, then changed the boot order in the BIOS and rebooted. I have two disks called **OS** visible in the File Manager. One is active (C:) - but how do I make sure that it's on the SSD? I open "properties" of drive C: in the File Manager, but there is nothing to indicate where it's located in the physical sense (SSD or HDD).

Comment: I think you can drill down from the Explorer properties to driver and device properties (for all volumes) where you can check model or manufacturer.

Comment: I believe this question is clear enough and not too broad. OP needed to know about the appropriate tool to get them the information they require, and gave us sufficient information in their question to make that clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You find this information most easily in Disk Management.

Open your start menu and begin typing "disk management", once this application shows in the results open it.

You'll now see a list of all of the disks on your computer and the partitions on them and the drive letters associated with those partitions.